# Dealing with Ranked Ordered Lists data in an efficient way with pandas

Tags: pandas

I'm dealing with ranked ordered list data at massive scale. I need to compare how individuals rank institutions/programs across periods. I need help figuring out which is the most efficient way to deal with this.

- A ranked ordered list (ROL): a report by individual in which they rank programs in institutions from most preferred to least preferred (0 being the most preferred).
- Operations: I need to run multiple operations between ROLs. Such as if the order changes, are new institutions or programs are added, and a lot more that I'm not detailing here.

I started using dictionaries because I'm familiar with them, but for a subsample my code is taking 28 hours to run. I need to speed this up a lot. I'm particularly looking for advice in which is the most efficient way to work with this type of data.

Below there is a fake data set on which I'm running the code.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# generate fake data frame
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 1, 0, 100, 101], [1, 2, 0, 100, 101], [1, 2, 1, 100, 102], [2, 1, 0, 100, 101], [2, 2, 0, 100, 101], [2, 2, 1, 200, 202], [3, 1, 0, 100, 101], [3, 1, 1, 200, 201], [3, 2, 0, 100, 101], [3, 2, 1, 200, 201], [4, 1, 0, 100, 101], [4, 1, 1, 200, 201], [4, 2, 0, 200, 201], [4, 2, 1, 100, 101] ], columns=['id_individual', 'period', 'rank', 'id_institution', 'id_program'])


df['change_app'] = False 
df['change_order'] = False
df['add_newinst'] = False
df['add_newprog'] = False

for indiv in df['id_individual'].unique():

    # recover rank of each individual for each period    
    r_pre = df.loc[(df['id_individual'] == indiv) & (df['period'] == 1)]
    r_post = df.loc[(df['id_individual'] == indiv) & (df['period'] == 2)] 
    
    # generate empty dict to store ranks 
    rank_pre = {}
    rank_post = {}

    # extract institution and program and assign to dictionary
    for i in range(0, len(r_pre)):
        rank_pre[i] = r_pre['id_institution'].loc[r_pre['rank'] == i].values[0], r_pre['id_program'].loc[r_pre['rank'] == i].values[0]

    for i in range(0, len(r_post)):
        rank_post[i] = r_post['id_institution'].loc[r_post['rank'] == i].values[0], r_post['id_program'].loc[r_post['rank'] == i].values[0]
    

    # if dictionaries are different, then compute some cases
    if rank_pre != rank_post:
        # Replace change app to true 
        df['change_app'].loc[(df['id_individual'] == indiv)] = True

        # check if it was a reorder
        df['change_order'].loc[(df['id_individual'] == indiv)] = (set(rank_pre.values()) == set(rank_post.values())) & (len(rank_pre) == len(rank_post))

        # get the set of values in the first position of the tuple
        programs_pre = set(rank_pre.values())
        programs_post = set(rank_post.values())

        inst_pre = set([x[0] for x in rank_pre.values()])
        inst_post = set([x[0] for x in rank_post.values()]) 

        # Added institution: if set of inst_post has an element that is not in inst_pre 
        df['add_newinst'].loc[(df['id_individual'] == indiv)] = len(inst_post - inst_pre) > 0

        # Added program: if set of programs_post has an element that is not in programs_pre
        df['add_newprog'].loc[(df['id_individual'] == indiv)] = len(programs_post - programs_pre) > 0

df.head(14)
```

Expected Output:

```
    id_individual  period  rank  id_institution  id_program  change_app  change_order  add_newinst  add_newprog
0               1       1     0             100         101        True         False        False         True
1               1       2     0             100         101        True         False        False         True
2               1       2     1             100         102        True         False        False         True
3               2       1     0             100         101        True         False         True         True
4               2       2     0             100         101        True         False         True         True
5               2       2     1             200         202        True         False         True         True
6               3       1     0             100         101       False         False        False        False
7               3       1     1             200         201       False         False        False        False
8               3       2     0             100         101       False         False        False        False
9               3       2     1             200         201       False         False        False        False
10              4       1     0             100         101        True          True        False        False
11              4       1     1             200         201        True          True        False        False
12              4       2     0             200         201        True          True        False        False
13              4       2     1             100         101        True          True        False        False
```

- I tried: performing operations over ranked ordered lists from individuals using pandas/dictionaries.
- I expected: low computing time.
- For 500.000 individuals, comparing ranked ordered lists is taking around 20 hours

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making some pivot tables that we can perform some vectorized functions on should perform far faster than any manual loop...

```
# Test Data
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 1, 0, 100, 101], [1, 2, 0, 100, 101], [1, 2, 1, 100, 102], [2, 1, 0, 100, 101], [2, 2, 0, 100, 101], [2, 2, 1, 200, 202], [3, 1, 0, 100, 101], [3, 1, 1, 200, 201], [3, 2, 0, 100, 101], [3, 2, 1, 200, 201], [4, 1, 0, 100, 101], [4, 1, 1, 200, 201], [4, 2, 0, 200, 201], [4, 2, 1, 100, 101] ], columns=['id_individual', 'period', 'rank', 'id_institution', 'id_program'])

# Pivot Config, we'll use this twice~
config = {
    'index': 'id_individual',
    'columns': 'period',
    'values': ['id_institution', 'id_program']
}
# First Pivot Table will be to look at unique values by period:
unique = df.pivot_table(**config, aggfunc=set)

# To look for changes, it'll help if there aren't missing values
# So, let's do a reindex trick to extract those missing values:
names = ['id_individual', 'period', 'rank']
df = (df.set_index(names)
        .reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product(df[names].apply(set), names=names))
        .reset_index())

# Now, we can make the Pivot Table of changes:
changes = df.pivot_table(**config, aggfunc=tuple)

# You're looking for a transform, so we'll set the index we're using
# to facilitate this. We'll also drop the NaN values we created, 
# and convert back to integers.
df = df.set_index('id_individual').dropna().astype(int)

# Let's take the cross section of each period; looking at changes.
p1_c, p2_c = [changes.xs(x, level='period', axis=1) for x in (1,2)]

# It was changed if either column had any change:
was_changed = p1_c.ne(p2_c).any(1)
df['change_app'] = was_changed

# Let's take the cross section of each period; looking at unique values.
p1_u, p2_u = [unique.xs(x, level='period', axis=1) for x in (1,2)]

# First, are they the same?
same_vals = p1_u.eq(p2_u).all(1)

# If they're the same, and were changed, it was just an order change:
df['change_order'] = was_changed & same_vals

# We take advantage of set logic here, new things have been added
# if the first is a proper subset (<) of the second:
df['add_newinst'] = p1_u.id_institution.lt(p2_u.id_institution)
df['add_newprog'] = p1_u.id_program.lt(p2_u.id_program)

# Reset the index back to where we started:
df = df.reset_index()
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    id_individual  period  rank  id_institution  id_program  change_app  change_order  add_newinst  add_newprog
0               1       1     0             100         101        True         False        False         True
1               1       2     0             100         101        True         False        False         True
2               1       2     1             100         102        True         False        False         True
3               2       1     0             100         101        True         False         True         True
4               2       2     0             100         101        True         False         True         True
5               2       2     1             200         202        True         False         True         True
6               3       1     0             100         101       False         False        False        False
7               3       1     1             200         201       False         False        False        False
8               3       2     0             100         101       False         False        False        False
9               3       2     1             200         201       False         False        False        False
10              4       1     0             100         101        True          True        False        False
11              4       1     1             200         201        True          True        False        False
12              4       2     0             200         201        True          True        False        False
13              4       2     1             100         101        True          True        False        False
```

---

~Large Frame Test - 200k IDs~

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from time import time

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 1, 0, 100, 101], [1, 2, 0, 100, 101], [1, 2, 1, 100, 102], [2, 1, 0, 100, 101], [2, 2, 0, 100, 101], [2, 2, 1, 200, 202], [3, 1, 0, 100, 101], [3, 1, 1, 200, 201], [3, 2, 0, 100, 101], [3, 2, 1, 200, 201], [4, 1, 0, 100, 101], [4, 1, 1, 200, 201], [4, 2, 0, 200, 201], [4, 2, 1, 100, 101] ], columns=['id_individual', 'period', 'rank', 'id_institution', 'id_program'])
# 7 million rows, 200k individuals:
df = pd.concat([df.assign(id_individual=df.id_individual.add(4*x)) for x in range(50000)], ignore_index=True)

start = time()
config = {
    'index': 'id_individual',
    'columns': 'period',
    'values': ['id_institution', 'id_program']
}
unique = df.pivot_table(**config, aggfunc=set)
names = ['id_individual', 'period', 'rank']
df = (df.set_index(names)
        .reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product(df[names].apply(set), names=names))
        .reset_index())
changes = df.pivot_table(**config, aggfunc=tuple)
df = df.set_index('id_individual').dropna().astype(int)
p1_c, p2_c = [changes.xs(x, level='period', axis=1) for x in (1,2)]
was_changed = p1_c.ne(p2_c).any(1)
df['change_app'] = was_changed
p1_u, p2_u = [unique.xs(x, level='period', axis=1) for x in (1,2)]
same_vals = p1_u.eq(p2_u).all(1)
df['change_order'] = was_changed & same_vals
df['add_newinst'] = p1_u.id_institution.lt(p2_u.id_institution)
df['add_newprog'] = p1_u.id_program.lt(p2_u.id_program)
df = df.reset_index()
print('Time Taken:', round(time()-start, 2), 'seconds')

# Output:
Time Taken: 12.87 seconds
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Incredible speed boost. I would still like to know which is the "best theoretical way" to deal with this type of data. But pivot tables are for sure faster than dictionaries by orders of magnitude. Thanks! :)

Comment: The shortest answer to "best theoretical way", while still using pandas, is anything vectorized. You may get marginalized improvements with other vectorized approaches, but nothing that relies primarily on a standard for-loop will ever come close.